# Cannot load HTML partial with AJAX in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to load an HTML partial in my "app" that are running I an Android `webview`. Everything is made with HTML, CSS, and jQuery.

Every time my code is trying to load an HTMl partial it returns an error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///W:/smarthubwebapp/public_html/html/pageHtml/login.html. Cross
>   origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: HTTP, data,
>   chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

I know in this case it loaded in chrome and not in the Android `webview` I want to use in the end.

All the files that I use in the project local files so they are called with the "file:///" protocol in the webview. Should it not work if I just open the index file in the browser and how do I fix this?

My ajax piece looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "html/pageHtml/" + pageToLoad + ".html",
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (response) {
        $("#pageContainer").html("<div id='innerPageContainer'>" + response + "</div>");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        $("#pageContainer").html("<div id='innerPageContainer'>" + JSON.stringify(status) + "</div>");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the crossDomain property to true in the Ajax properties, hence the error.

Simply remove that.

The error says it all, 'File' requests can be used with crossDomain calls.

Comment: I also found an error in a different script. Thanks for the help!